# C# check if a process exists then close it

Tags: c#

I'm trying to Close a process within C# but how do I check if is open first?  Users asked for this feature and some of them will be still using the close button of the other process.

So, right now works fine:

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName")[0].CloseMainWindow();
```

Now, how do I check first that it exists, this doesn't work:

```
if ( Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName")[0] != null ) {...}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this to avoid the race condition in which a process closes after the first call to `GetProcessesByName`:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName");
if (processes.Length > 0)
    processes[0].CloseMainWindow();
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're planning to deploy this application on a wide range of machines, you will want to know that this code can sometimes fail.

The `Process` class in .NET is based on Windows performance counters, which on some machines can be disabled through the registry. When this happens, the call to the `Process.GetProcessesByName` method will throw an exception.

I think this situation is typical for machines with various "clean up / performance tuning" applications which, among other stuff, disable the performance counters in order to supposedly improve the machine's performance.

In the past this has repeatedly caused me pain with some percentage of my customers' client machines, which led me to explore other (if somewhat limited or cumbersome) alternatives, like making calls to Win API directly using PInvoke to iterate over the processes.

Another possible solution would be to ensure that your installer or application enables performance counters, or at least knows how to deal with them being disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the advise Ran, I appreciate the time you are saving me.

Comment: For this project, I'll be better only catching the exception. I'm pretty sure in some labs performance counters are disabled and it won't be a good idea to mess with the admin decisions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName").Length > 0) {...}
```

Comment: I think a race condition may be hiding inside that elipsis!

Comment: @Jeffrey L Whitledge: Good catch.  My focus was too narrow.

Answer (score 4):

You could also just loop, which works fine if there aren't any.

```
foreach(Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName"))
{
    p.CloseMainWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName").FirstOrDefault() != null
```

Comment: Thank you Jani, I'll prefer the Andy advise, because it doesn't use linq

Comment: @romkyns       using (var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("").FirstOrDefault())
      {
          if(process !=null)
          {
          }
      }


make even more sense :-)

Comment: @Jani if that was humor then I didn't get it, sorry :)

Comment: @romkyns No it's not totally joke, maybe you need the reference to the process you're looking for so I think this approach is actually fits.

Comment: @Jani ok got it. FirstOrDefault makes sense in that context, but your answer alone really made me wonder why not just use "Any".

Answer (score 1):

You could use `GetProcessesByName` like so:

```
foreach(var application in Process.GetProcessesByName("ApplicationName"))
        {
            application.CloseMainWindow();
        }
```

If you meant to kill the application, then you could do this instead:

```
foreach(var application in Process.GetProcessesByName("ApplicationName"))
        {
            application.Kill();
        }
```